# Does the baby in the womb get effected by the mental state of the mother?

Tags: development, pregnancy

Yesterday for some reason I was quite depressed and frightened at night. For the first time I felt the baby kicking all night in my womb (6th month).

Well, that can be a coincidence.

Anyways, does the baby in the womb get effected by the mental state of the mother? In what way if yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond depression or fear, there is evidence that a wide variety of emotions can be chemically sent to the fetus. according to an [article on Psychology Science](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/news/releases/a-fetus-can-sense-moms-psychological-state.html)

Also, at least one source appears to suggest that [consistency is important](http://www.myhealthnewsdaily.com/1933-pregnancy-mothers-mental-state-baby-development.html), in that large changes to mood may slow mental and motor skills.

Answer (score 5):

When you are stressed, you release hormones such as cortisol into your blood, as well as into the amniotic fluid surrounding your baby, according to [at least one study](http://www.news-medical.net/news/2007/06/01/25891.aspx).  That said, while I haven't read it I know the book [Origins](http://www.amazon.ca/Origins-Months-Before-Birth-Shape/dp/0743296621/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325874667&sr=8-1) reviewed the evidence and found that some stress seems to have a positive impact.

So your child in utero does indeed have some level of understanding of your mental state, but the details seem to be quite complicated and only roughly understood.